# Time complexity of algorithm T(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Could someone tell me the time complexity of this algorithm? The book says it is T(n) = (n-1)(1+n/4) = O(n2)

```
for ( i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++) {
for ( j = 0 ; j <= n) {
cout << i << j ;
j = j + floor(n/4) ;
}
}
```

But i don't know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop iterates `n-1` times, the inner loop iterates `n/4` times . The complexity for the algorithm is (n-1)*(n/4)= (n^2-n)/4 = `O(n^2)`